# Necessary phase shift of op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, phase-shift, frequency-response, inverting-amplifier

My lecturer said that, for any system where the amplitude response varies with frequency, such as for an op amp, there will necessarily be a frequency-dependent phase shift between the input and output to prevent causality violation. I believe this effect is named after someone, or at least has a specific name, but I cannot seem to find what it is. Would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction so I can look into this further!

Comment: Did you ask the lecturer ?

Comment: @rsg1710 Barkhausen Criteria has to do with feedback stability.